# Android progress bar not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I am trying to fetch a list of earthquakes using an API. All I want is that, if internet connection is not available, the screen must tell about it to the user, else while data has not yet been fetched, a progress bar should show up to let the user know that fetching is in progress and when done fetching, the progress bar goes away and the recycler view displays the list of earthquakes. But for some reason, the progress bar is now working properly. Either it doesn't show up at all or  if it does, it doesn't go away . Here is my Main Activity class:

```
public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyModel mMyModel;
    private ViewModelProvider mViewModelProvider;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private TextView mEmptyView;
    private EarthquakeAdapter mEarthquakeAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);
        mEmptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        // get the progress bar to indicate loading
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.loading_bar);
        // set a view model provider for the current activity
        mViewModelProvider = new ViewModelProvider(this);
        // get the view model for the class
        mMyModel = mViewModelProvider.get(MyModel.class);
        // find a reference to the {@link RecyclerView} in the layout
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.earthquakes);
        mConnectivityManager = getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
        mEmptyView.setText("No internet available");
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        mConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fetchData();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);// hide the progress bar
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// make the recycler view visible
    }

    private void fetchData(){
        // fetch the list of earthquakes
        mMyModel.getEarthquakes().observe(EarthquakeActivity.this, new Observer<ArrayList<Earthquake>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
                // set up recycler view with this data, this will work even if you rotate the device
                setUpRecyclerView(earthquakes);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
        if(earthquakes == null || earthquakes.size() == 0) {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mEmptyView.setText(R.string.no_data_available);
            mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // create adapter passing in the earthquake data
            mEarthquakeAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(EarthquakeActivity.this, earthquakes);
            // attach the adapter to the recyclerView to populate the items
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mEarthquakeAdapter);
            // set the layout manager to position the items
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(EarthquakeActivity.this));
            // click listener for when an item is clicked
            mEarthquakeAdapter.setClickListener((view, position) -> searchWeb(earthquakes.get(position).getUrl()));
        }
    }

    private void searchWeb(String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,url);
        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

and my recycler view xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/earthquakes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/no_data_available"
        />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

In case needed, here is my MyModel.java file which itself was a herculean task to setup properly

```
public class MyModel extends ViewModel {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyModel";
    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Earthquake>> mMutableLiveData;
    public ArrayList<Earthquake> mEarthquakes;

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Earthquake>> getEarthquakes() {
        mMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        // call the API
        init();
        return mMutableLiveData;
    }

    public void init() {
        // perform the network request on separate thread
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // create array list of earthquakes
                mEarthquakes = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2021-06-01&limit=300");
                mMutableLiveData.postValue(mEarthquakes);
            }
        });
        executorService.shutdown();

    }


}
```

Please explain what I am doing wrong. I recently learnt multithreading and API basics so I don't have any idea about my mistake. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition. Move the two lines in `onCreate()` for setting the visibility on the progress bar and the _RecyclerView_ to just before the network callback registration to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: You may have a race condition in the observer as well although I am not sure about that. Log an entry to logcat every time you change the visibility of the progress bar to see if there is a sequencing problem.

Comment: @Cheticamp Putting them before the line `mConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback` also doesn't solve the problem. I can try looking at the logcats again and again but that would be time consuming. I wonder is it supposed to be this hard? Showing a progress bar shouldn't be this painful :(

Comment: Ok, I made it work now by making the progress bar invisible in `setUpRecyclerView` and it works now. I did this when I saw in the Logcats that the call to `setUpRecyclerView` happens twice whereas call to those two lines happens only once. I am not sure why.

Comment: `onChanged()` is called when the observer first becomes active if a value has been set for the observed value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this in your MainActivity =>

```
mConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    
                    fetchData();
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new View.OnCompleteListener) {
       mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);});
```

Comment: I don't understand how I need to do `.addOnCompleteListener ` here. Can u format the code properly , please?

Comment: If i just copy the code directly , I get an error `Cannot resolve method addOnCompleteListener` , which is why I am saying that I don't understand where I am supposed to add it .